# JQuery validate not working after modifying rules

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I have two html elements. One is a select box and under it is a text input box. If I change the select box above, then I want to change the JQuery validate rules for the text input box. The code below seems to run through correctly (labels are changed), but the validation doesn't occur on a focusout or a clickout event like I would expect it to.

Here is my code that changes the rules when I change a select box value. Am I missing something?

```js
$('#Countries.selectpicker').on('change', function() {
  $("#Location").val('');
  var selected = $(this).find("option:selected").val();
  if (selected != "0") {
    //alert("other country selected");
    $(".locationLabel").text("City");
    $("#Location").attr("placeholder", "e.g. London");
    $("#Location").attr("type", "string");
    $("#Location").rules("remove");
    $('#Location').rules("add", {
      required: true,
      minlength: 3,
      maxlength: 40,
      messages: {
        required: "Required input",
        minlength: jQuery.validator.format("Please, {0} characters are necessary"),
        maxlength: jQuery.validator.format("Please, {0} characters are necessary")
      }
    });
  } else {
    //alert("us selected");
    $(".locationLabel").text("Zip Code");
    $("#Location").attr("placeholder", "e.g. 94901");
    $("#Location").attr("type", "number");
    $("#Location").rules("remove");
    $('#Location').rules("add", {
      required: true,
      minlength: 5,
      maxlength: 5,
      messages: {
        required: "Required input",
        minlength: jQuery.validator.format("Please, {0} characters are necessary"),
        maxlength: jQuery.validator.format("Please, {0} characters are necessary")
      }
    });
  }
});
```

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/22recekc/1/ ?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/22recekc/2/

Comment: trying this link above why am I seeing an error after a select change occurs and I try entering in 3 characters? http://jsfiddle.net/22recekc/3/

Comment: also why isn't the validation being triggered when I click out of the text field?

Comment: by default the blur validation will happen only after submit button(or the form validate method is called by some other means) is clicked once

Comment: I'm confused. If I change the rules, then type 'Lon' and press tab to move the cursor out of the text field I want the validation rules to be checked! but it isn't http://jsfiddle.net/22recekc/3/

Comment: the idea is one select will check against a zipcode the other will check against a city. So my custom validations go off and check. But I want them to check when I loose focus of the text field or click away. It seems to be working fine for the zip code, which is the first set of rules applied. It just doesn't do anything after I switch the rules (to city)

Comment: see http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/22recekc/4/

Answer (score 0):

You can have a custom blur handler to trigger the validation manually like

```js
jQuery(function($) {
  var $Countries = $('#Countries.selectpicker');
  var validator = $('#myform').validate({
    onfocusout: function(el) {
      this.element(el)
    },
    rules: {
      Location: {
        required: true,
        minlength: function() {
          return $Countries.val() == '0' ? 5 : 3
        },
        maxlength: function() {
          return $Countries.val() == '0' ? 5 : 40
        }
      }
    },
    messages: {
      Location: {
        required: "Required input",
        minlength: jQuery.validator.format("Please, {0} characters are necessary"),
        maxlength: jQuery.validator.format("Please, {0} characters are necessary")
      }
    }
  });

  $('#Countries.selectpicker').on('change', function() {
    $("#Location").val('');
    var selected = $(this).find("option:selected").val();
    if (selected != "0") {
      //alert("other country selected");
      $(".locationLabel").text("City");
      $("#Location").attr("placeholder", "e.g. London");
      $("#Location").attr("type", "string");
    } else {
      //alert("us selected");
      $(".locationLabel").text("Zip Code");
      $("#Location").attr("placeholder", "e.g. 94901");
      $("#Location").attr("type", "number");
    }
    $("#myform").valid()
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-validate/1.13.1/jquery.validate.js"></script>
<form id="myform" method="post" action="">
  <select id="Countries" class="selectpicker" name="Countries">
    <option>0</option>
    <option>!0</option>
  </select>
  <input id="Location" name="Location">
  <input type="submit" value="Save" />
</form>
```

Comment: this kinda changes the way I was doing it with dynamically changing the rules. is this way better? In my way I'm not calling any element.validate() method

Answer (score 0):

[Quote OP's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35859359/jquery-validate-not-working-after-modifying-rules#comment59384334_35859766),

> *"In my way I'm not calling any element.validate() method"*

Then that's your entire problem.  The `.validate()` method MUST first be used in order to initialize the jQuery Validate plugin on your form.  Without first initializing the plugin, the `.rules()` method is doing nothing.

```
$(document).ready(function() {  // DOM is ready

    $("#myform").validate({ // initialize the plugin on your form
        // initial rules & options
    });

    $('#Countries.selectpicker').on('change', function() {
        // now you can dynamically change the rules
        $("#Location").rules( ....

        // when you're done changing the rules, you can trigger an immediate test  
        $("#Location").valid();
    });

});
```